# Cannot make query substitutions

Tags: hooks, views, database

I am using Drupal 7 and Views 7.x-3.7 . I am trying to display posts on my site using a SQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.language AS node_language

FROM 

{node} node

ORDER BY node_title ASC
```

The problem with this query is that if I have multiple posts with the same title,then all are being displayed because the nid, which is the primary key, was added by Drupal. I have been trying to remove the nid by using the [`hook_views_query_substitutions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_substitutions/7) method, but I have had no success. The method is getting called, but my query is not being updated.

I call zz_views_api() from my zz.module, and have the following zz.views.inc

```
function zz_views_query_substitutions($view) {
  // description of  zz_views_query_substitutions().

  return array(
    'node.nid AS nid,' => ' ',
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a similar situation to [a question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106422/why-does-views-add-the-sort-field-as-a-select-expression) I asked a little while ago.

I solved it by using [`hook_views_query_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) to remove the fields I didn't need in the query.   In your case, it would probably look like:

```
function MYMOODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'MY_VIEW') {
    unset($query->fields['nid']);
  }
}
```

[`dpm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7) the `$query` to see what array keys are in `$query->fields` if that doesn't work.

Comment: This plus enabling pure distinct works, thanks. Can anybody still explain why the query substitution does not work ?